# CVS Replace and "Switch to Another Branch or Version" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

When I try to switch to a different branch of a project in my workspace, I use the "Replace With" or "Switch to Another Branch or Version" command. Most of the times, it does the job, but sometimes, the switch is partial, and I end up with a messed up project with mixed branch tags. It's really annoying because I end up checking stuff into the branch.

Has anyone else experienced the same? Can you suggest a solution?

Thanks. I'm using Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 1):

The [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-103.htm) explains the difference between "Replace With" and "Switch to Another Branch or Version".

> **Replace With > Another Branch or Version** - replace the Workbench resource with a specific version or branch that you select in the repository. When you select this option, another window opens, so that you can browse through the branch and version tags in the repository and select the one that you want.
>
> **Team > Switch to Another Branch or Version** - this update will replace Workbench resources with those on the tag specified in the Update dialog. The behavior differs from the above replace operations in that uncommitted modifications in the Workbench are not replaced but instead are "moved" to the resources from the selected tag. For more details on the specifics of this operation, see the CVS documentation at http://ximbiot.com/cvs/ relating to the use of the -r option with cvs update.